# MYSQL Update Trigger get updated row ID

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table in MySQL which I am updating. I would like the trigger to get the updated row ID so as to do some work with it. How can I do it? I can do this in SQL Server, but I am new to MySQL and couldn't find anything online.

UPDATE...

So I can't share the code, but this is basically want I want to do.

```
Table: 
**id** **product** **price**
1,     Coke,         2.05 USD 
2,     Sprite,       2.00 USD
3,     7Up,          2.10 USD
```

I want to update id 2, "Sprite" price to 2.50 USD. Now I will do this normally, but I need to run a Trigger that will update an Audit table. The Audit table will need to register the id of the product. So basically I need to know that the updated row's id was 2...

is there anything similar in sql?

Comment: Can you post your code? Do you mean do some work inside the trigger? Use a `FOR EACH ROW` and refer to the columns using the aliases `NEW.your_column` and `OLD.your_column`. Can you elaborate a bit more in detail?

Comment: As long as the id will not be changed you can use either `NEW.id` or `OLD.id` inside the trigger. I'll write an example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can refer to the `id` column using either `NEW.id` or `OLD.id` as long as the `id` column will not change.

Generally spoken, with the alias `NEW` you can get the current value of the updated column and with `OLD` you obtain the value that the column had before the update was performed.

```
CREATE TRIGGER au_product_table
    AFTER UPDATE ON product_table
    FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE audit
        SET product_id = NEW.id
        WHERE your_condition;
```