# MYSQL Select only edited row with trigger and insert into another table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need to create trigger that for every update on one table, write row or rows updated into another table. I've created this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_order_trigger
AFTER UPDATE ON sales_order
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO update_status_order (order_id, n_ordine, status, reparto)
SELECT o.order_id, s.increment_id, s.status, c.value
FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar c INNER JOIN sales_order_item o INNER 
JOIN sales_order s
ON o.product_id = c.entity_id 
WHERE c.attribute_id = 154 AND s.entity_id = o.order_id
GROUP BY o.order_id, c.value, s.increment_id;
```

When execute this trigger, it copy all rows from table sales_order to update_status_order. How can i do to copy only edited rows?

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23016807/mysql-update-trigger-get-updated-row-id

Comment: @lucumt i've cecked it but it's not compatible with select, because i need to get data from more tables.